# Can I define an api that remains the same across implementations?

Tags: java, gradle

For example, lets say I have a gradle project with 4 sub projects: :api, :impla, :implb, and :runner.

:api contains interfaces with methods that should be implemented by the implementations

:impla and :implb are the implementations

:runner uses either of those implementations

Can I have :runner always expect a compelete implementaton of :api from either implementation (eg. every interface has an implementation, with the same name across implementations so the source of :runner doesn't have to be changed) without doing it manually?

Comment: why would you bother with the names of the implementing classes? read up on "coding to interfaces". And, no, you can't force limitations of names of classes that implement your interface(s) afaik

Comment: > why would you bother with the names of the implementing classes?
I am trying to have (:runner in this example) be able to be built against either :impla or :implb without needing to change the code, so without needing to change imports

Comment: why would you need to change your code?